# Why url address duplicates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, networking, axios

I'm making react-app on Mac and it works on the local server and gh page. But when i'm making it on Windows, the url dublicates and data from local json file (which i put to folder 'public) doesn't work.

[image]

```
componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('./phone.json').then(({data}) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.setState({
        phone: data
      })
    })
  }
```

It makes this url

```
https://localhost:3000/%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5C%5CMyWebShop%5Cphone.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

To prevent circular dependency, you just need to put the title of your domain.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('/MyWebShop/./phone.json').then(({data}) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.setState({
        phone: data
      })
    })
  }
```